# How can I remove non characters from a dataframe? python beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe

df

```
 ID    col1
 1     The quick brown fox jumped hf_093*&
 2     fox run jump *& #7
```

How can I parse out non-characters in this dataframe?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
posts = ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," 
",posts).split())
```

Comment: did you wanted to remove just the `*&` or the `hf_093` as well? Are all the elements you wanted to remove ending with `*&`?

Comment: Why have you tagged Beautifulsoup?

Comment: Everything in your dataframe is a character. What do you mean by `non-characters'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [**inbuilt functions**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2], 'col1': ['The quick brown fox jumped hf_093*&', 'fox run jump *& #7']}).set_index('ID')

df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('[^\w\s]+', '')
print(df)
```

Which yields

```
                                 col1
ID                                   
1   The quick brown fox jumped hf_093
2                     fox run jump  7
```

---

This removes everything *not* `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and whitespaces.

---

If you want finer control, you could use a function

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(?i)\b[a-z]+\b')

def remover(row):
    words = " ".join([word 
        for word in row.split()
        if rx.match(word)])
    return words

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(remover)
print(df)
```

Which would yield

```
                          col1
ID                            
1   The quick brown fox jumped
2                 fox run jump
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware pandas already has a replace function that supports regex.  My codes look like a mouthful :|

Comment: @Idlehands: `pandas` is indeed remarkably well designed.

Comment: @OptimusPrime: Glad to help here.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is removing the strings that contains special characters:

**Regex:**

```
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub("(?:\w*[^\w ]+\w*)", "", x).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
                            0
0  The quick brown fox jumped 
1                fox run jump
```

An alternative, non-regex solution for the crazy list comprehension enthusiasts:

```
unwanted = '!@#$%^&*()'    
df.applymap(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if not any(c in i for c in unwanted)]))
```

**Output:**

```
                            0
0  The quick brown fox jumped
1                fox run jump
```

Removes any strings that has the unwanted special characters in them.

Comment: how can i do this in a dataframe?

Comment: You can define it as a function and use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: @OptimusPrime actually should be [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) in your case.  See my edit.